# Why does CLGeocoder crash upon call

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mapkit, core-location

I want to convert an Address into a Location on the Mac for routing purposes.

I am using

```
[[CLGeocoder alloc] geocodeAddressString:@"1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014" 
                       completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
        if(placemarks){
            NSLog(@"%@", placemarks);
        }
    }];
```

Upon runtime the execution crashes with a Bad Excess on the snippets first line.
Does anyone has an idea on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init `CLGeocoder`.

```
CLGeocoder *geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geoCoder geocodeAddressString:@"1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014"
             completionHandler:^(NSArray<CLPlacemark *> * _Nullable placemarks, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                 if(error){
                     NSLog(@"%@", error);
                 }
                 if(placemarks){
                     NSLog(@"%@", placemarks);
                 }
             }];
```